# How to animate svg dotted line from one point to another?

Tags: html, css, xml, animation, svg

I want to understand how to animate like this:

[image: PIC1]

[image: PIC2]

[image: PIC3]

I have this svg code (x1,x2,y1,y2 are dynamic assignment)

```html
<svg id={props.id} class="connect" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="100%">
   <line lass="path_in" x1={x1} y1={y1} x2={x2} y2={y2} stroke="#5184AF" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 10"/>
</svg>
```

I try this:

```css
svg .path_in {
    stroke-dasharray: 1300;
    animation: dash 4s linear;
    -webkit-animation: dash 4s linear;
  }
  @keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously "lass" instead of "class" is a copy and paste error, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to animate it would be using SMIL animations like this:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
   <line lass="path_in" x1="10" y1="25" x2="10" y2="25" stroke="#5184AF" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 10">
    <animate 
       attributeName="x2"
       attributeType="XML"
       from="10" to="90"
       dur="4s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </line>
</svg>
```

In this demo the `<animate>` element is animating the x2 attribute `from="10"` (the same value as x1) `to="90"`. The animation's duration is 4 second: `dur="4s"`

Observation: you don't need `width="100%"` since if you don't declare the width and height of the svg element by default will take all the available width.

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for